# Работа с файлами laravel, как скрыть storage?

Tags: php, laravel, storage

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно использовать файловую систему laravel.
На примере изображений, мне их нужно сохранять в /storage/images/.../image.jpg
На фронте нужно получить адрес к картинке - `http://localhost/images/avatars/image.jpg`
Но по файкту я могу получить только такой вариант `http://localhost/storage/images/avatars/image.jpg`
Вот мои конфиги по дискам:

```
    'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/images',
        'visibility' => 'public'
    ],

]
```

Если попытаться получить через asset то получаю 404
`{{ asset('images/avatars/image.jpg') }}` Если через класс Storage::url() то получается, но урл не правильный.

Что мне нужно сделать чтобы получить нужный урл и при этом хранить файлы не в папке `public/images`, а в `storage/app/public/images` ?

И второй вопрос, как закрыть прямой доступ через GET запрос к каталогу storage?
При запросе адреса `http://localhost/storage` или `http://localhost/storage/app` и др., получить 404 ошибку со стандартным шаблоном ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk - `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @MoloF И в итоге я получаю вот такой адрес http://localhost/storage/images/avatars/image.jpg, а нужен http://localhost/images/avatars/image.jpg

Comment: Или выход создавать символьную ссылку со .../storage/app/public/images в .../public/images?

Answer (score 2):

1. Делаете симлинк(ярлык) storage/app/public -> public/storage/

   php artisan storage:link
2. Простешая запись ваших файлов через POST (**image** - это имя input поля для файла) -

   $my_image =  $request->file('image')->store('images','public');

либо с оригинальным именем $image_name( сами задаете вместе с раширением )

```
$my_image =  $request->file('image')->storeAs('images',$image_name,'public');
```

store('images','public') - тут первое это папка куда положится файл, а второе драйвер, которые используется для сохранинея этого файла(по дефолту он сохранит в storage/app/public). Т.е. файл будет лежать в storage/app/public/images/. Название файла будет сгенерировано автоматически.

3. Достать изображение из хранилища(например, в blade - шаблоне )

   {{ asset('storage/'.$my_image) }}

ПС. Ваш собственный драйвер не верен

```
'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/images',
        'visibility' => 'public'
    ],
```

Путь куда все это будет сохраняться "имя_вашего_проекта_"/images/app/public/images .

Comment: Ну так это не решает проблему мы получим в html не тот адрес который нужен мы получим <img src="http://localhost/storage/images/image.jpg"> а нужно  <img src="http://localhost/images/image.jpg">, пока не нашел другого решения кроме как юзать символическую ссылку